# Python PIL Library MemoryError

Tags: python, memory, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to stitch together images with Python (PIL library).
The image is pretty big and when allocating a place for the result, it produces a memory error.
The error has no relation to my code, as it crashes without any code but this:

```
from PIL import Image
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(17*1388, 23*1038), (250,250,250))
```

The error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Myx.png)

Comment: the final result is an image combining a set of 391 images (17 over 23 images, each of size 1388 over 1038 pixels), hence the new_image size which seems too much

Comment: it consumes to much memory

Comment: whats your system configutation?

Comment: I know it's consuming too much memory. My question is where does this limitation come from? from the library itself? my machine? @Mehamaan - what I meant is if there is some configuration file or settings that can be adjusted in order to hold such a large image.

Comment: What I did, for now, as a workaround, is to drop one column and one row of the final image (having it result from a set of 16x22 images instead of a 17x23) which worked and the final result was a 90MB JPEG image - BUT this just a workaround, not the desired outcome